# Write a program that repeatedly asks a user to enter a positive integer until they enter a positive integer number

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program that uses a while loop to repeatedly ask a user to input a positive integer until they do but my code keeps printing the number after the while look asks a second time and I don't want that. This is my code below:

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

while num <= 0:
    print(int(input("Enter a positive integer: ")))

print(f"{num} is positive.")
```

this is what prints when I execute the code:

Enter a positive integer: -4

Enter a positive integer: -3

-3

Enter a positive integer: -6

-6

Enter a positive integer:

Comment: Because you print the number with `print` function. Also, you don't write the users input to `num` inside of the loop, so `num` never changes after the first line

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

while num <= 0:
    num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

print(f"{num} is positive.")
```

This should work. Your while-loop is checking if the number is positive, but you are not changing the number based on the new input.

Comment: `print` returns `None`. Try your code before posting the answer

Comment: it keeps printing the number like above

Answer (score 0):

```
num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))

while num <= 0:
    num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    
print(f"{num} is positive.")
```

This could be a possible solution.

This solution only prints when the user enters any positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

Can use a `while True` loop instead, then `break` the loop when your condition (positive integer inputted) is satisfied:

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    if num > 0:
        print(f"{num} is positive")
        break
```